# Make Azure SQL database offline in a failover group

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, database-replication, disaster-recovery

Any idea how I can turn off/bring down primary Azure SQL database / SQL Server in fail over group to replicate an actual scenario like a data center is down? I tried renaming but doesn't work. All I am trying to do is take one of the Azure SQL databases offline in the failover group. Any ideas how it can be done please?

Comment: Other than deleting it, there is no way today to simulate an outage currently.

Comment: Is deleting the primary db same as the db down?

Comment: Not exactly, no.  I'm not suggesting you delete the database to test failover, but that is the closest thing currently there.  You would probably be better off with a mocking layer if you want to test this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a forced failover which may result in data loss same as a server down or datacenter down scenario. Note that is not the same as a manual or friendly failover using the portal, on which case there is no danger of data loss.

You can use REST API to generate a a forced failover as explained on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/failovergroups/forcefailoverallowdataloss) documentation.

Comment: True but what we want a scenario where we have a failovergroup and the primary is not accessiable/down so that we can do a manual failover to seocndary.

Comment: My suggestion is the closest to a solution you can get at this time. I see now you have edited your original question